# Cannot create a SEO route in rails with blogpost and category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues with routes.

I have these models:

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :section
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :contents
end
```

I'm using FriendlyID Gem, so I have a slug parameter in every model.

I want for a content an url like

```
https://example.com/section_slug/content_slug
```

I try with

```
  resources :sections, only: [:show] do
    resources :contents, only: [:show]
  end
```

But the result is

```
/sections/:section_id/contents/:id(.:format)
```

I try with

```
match '/:category/:title', via: [:get], to: 'contents#show'
```

but is doesn't work

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

U can use the `path` option in your routes like this:

```rb
resources :sections, only: [:show], path: '' do
  resources :contents, only: [:show], path: ''
end
```

This will replace the `/sections/` with an empty string and the same for `/contents/` so you will end up with an url like:
`/:section_id/:content_id/`